# Objective Sharpie Error: Failed to run pod list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, cocoapods, objective-sharpie

I'm using Cocoapods 1.4.0, Visual Studio Community for Mac 7.3.3 (build 12), Objective Sharpie 3.4.0-c0f0e73, Mac OS 10.12.6 (Sierra)

whenever I try to add the example Cocoapod on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod/

I get the following error:

```
mbp:iOS user$ sharpie pod init ios AFNetworking
** Setting up CocoaPods master repo ...
   (this may take a while the first time)
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/user/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin
  --progress
  remote: Counting objects: 1101, done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (224/224), done.        
  remote: Total 1101 (delta 540), reused 465 (delta 465), pack-reused 402        
  Receiving objects: 100% (1101/1101), 165.70 KiB | 2.91 MiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (690/690), completed with 258 local objects.
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     6a7b167b826..807a5994b64  master     -> origin/master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/user/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse
  --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/user/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard
  origin/master
  HEAD is now at 807a5994b64 [Add] SwiftyGif 4.1.0
Setup completed
** Searching for requested CocoaPods ...
error: Failed to run pod list
```

Does anyone know why, and who to work this around?

I'm just  trying to add a Pod.

Note: I have no issues when trying to use CocoaPods on an Native iOS Project

Comment: Try to downgrade Cocoapods  or Objective Sharpie

Comment: I was using cocoapods 1.5, I downgraded to 1.3 then to 1.1 but still having the same issue : "error: Failed to run pod list"

Comment: I had the same error, over and over again, I was testing Xamarin with a well known library, at the end I went the React-Native way.

Comment: This issue seems to be still present 6 months after the original question was posted.

Comment: Actually 3 years later of the original date of this question and this bug is still not solved !! shame on Microsoft and shame on Xamarin team !! it has been this frustrating since years .. these guys don't really care about us dev community !

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me using a fresh install of CocoaPods and Objective Sharpie.

Install CocoaPods from Homebrew:

> brew install cocoapods

Find latest [Objective Sharpie release on the Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/ObjectiveSharpie) and install it by double clicking the pkg file.

Now just run the same command you already tried:

> sharpie pod init ios AFNetworking

```
--- ~/derp » sharpie pod init ios AFNetworking
** Setting up CocoaPods master repo ...
   (this may take a while the first time)
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.4.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/tomasci/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/tomasci/.ssh/cheesebaron-github':
  remote: Counting objects: 36, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
  remote: Total 36 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
  From ssh://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     e874a97a946..0d05aca4c0d  master     -> origin/master
  $ /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/tomasci/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/tomasci/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at 0d05aca4c0d [Add] XTFMDB 1.5.0

CocoaPods 1.6.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.6.0.beta.1

Setup completed
** Searching for requested CocoaPods ...
** Working directory:
**   - Writing Podfile ...
**   - Installing CocoaPods ...
**     (running `pod install --no-repo-update`)
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.4.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (3.2.1)
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/tomasci/.ssh/cheesebaron-github':
Generating Pods project
Skipping User Project Integration
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
**   Success! You can now use other `sharpie pod` commands.
```

The only thing that might be different here is that I have ssh config set up for GitHub.